# Android Portable Printing Task

Tags: android, bluetooth, printers

i need an app of mine to be able to connect to a portable printer via Bluetooth. Kinda like the system police here in India have. They send parking ticket-receipt/any other ticket-receipt from a blackberry phone to a printer and take out hard copy of the receipt. Is this at all possible in Android?? I have been trying to search on the net but haven't been able to come up with anything good.... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible in android. You can refer this sites for bluetooth coding idea

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html

Also there you can refer this for how bluetooth print app is made

[Bluetooth Printer issue in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145787/bluetooth-printer-issue-in-android)

Hope it helps