# Print data from android app using bluetooth printer

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth

I am developing an android app for restaurant . I want to print the bill after ordering from my app . I am using Bluetooth printer for the printing task . Any body having experience in  printing data  using Bluetooth printer ,please help with some suitable examples .

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I have experience of same application. You need to use `StreamConnection` class with the `InputStream` and `OutputStream` class.

First you need to make connection with Bluetooth Printer using its Bluetooth Address and then you need to send characters to print using `OutputStream` class.

On the printer side when it will fetch the characters it will directly start printing it.

```
private StreamConnection bConn = null; 
private DataOutputStream dos = null; 

 try
 {
    bConn = (StreamConnection) Connector.open(PrinterURL);
    dos = (DataOutputStream)bConn.openDataOutputStream();
    dos.writeUTF("\r\n");
    dos.writeUTF("===============================");dos.writeUTF("\r\n");
    dos.writeUTF("          GSECL Bill"); dos.writeUTF("\r\n");
    dos.writeUTF("===============================");dos.writeUTF("\r\n");
  }
  catch ( Exception e ) { System.out.println "Server Error: " + e.toString() );

finally
{
    try
        { 
        dos.close();
    bConn.close();
    }
    catch ( Exception e ) { }
    }
```

Comment: How can i get the  Bluetooth Address of bluetooth printer .

Comment: create a sample project that detects bluetooth devices, and from that, you can find it :)

Comment: sure, i suggest you to ask a new question, so it can be helpful for others as well.

Comment: @Lucifer hello, I want help..i want to use bluetooth printer..  in above code u have mention StreamConnection, bt i could not find it..and  'bConn = (StreamConnection) Connector.open(PrinterURL);' what is Connector here? plz help me..

Comment: @KinjalShah, Connector class is used to make HttpConection/StreamConnectoin in J2ME, you can search its description on google.com

Comment: @Lucifer I have followed this link. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145787/bluetooth-printer-issue-in-android] and use snap of it for printing. but problem is only first time its get printed.so can u help me to solve this problem? Thanks..

Comment: @KinjalShah sure, do one thing, ask a new fresh question with your code and error code ( if you have any ), this way you may get more response from other developers as well :)