# How to scan the printer connected to an android device

Tags: android, printing, device

How to scan the printer connected to the device and print the current screen. Any third party libraries available to scan and print operations. It should scan and get the IP of the printer connected.

Comment: Connected , how ? by USB, or Bluetooth ?

Comment: I need it for both. But, if you know for any one, please suggest me...

Comment: for scanning , i just [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12048935/996493) , please check it.

Comment: Also, check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12003555/996493) for bluetooth printing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a SO question [Bluetooth and WIFI Printing for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656199/bluetooth-and-wifi-printing-for-android?rq=1) where [Roy Samuel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/461269/roy-samuel) suggests

> Printing via Bluetooth on Android is not possible as of now , as Android does not support Bluetooth 'Profiles', such as BPP, HCRP  BIP etc. which are the common profiles used with Bluetooth Printing.
>   Currently, Android supports OPP (Object Push Profile) which is used to send files over Bluetooth.

Yet scanning the printer can be achieved through [How to detect bluetooth device How to detect bluetooth device and get the bluetooth address of detected device from android app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12048935/432903)

Comment: The bluetooth is not the only way to has a printer plugged in android device, with serial port too, how can I check or detect whether a printer is plugged on a serial port?