# printing file content using android Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, file-sharing

I want to print some content of file or say generate bill from my mobile device through Bluetooth enabled printer device.How can I generate bill using Bluetooth?

Comment: If you want to print something from your device via Bluetooth, then check below link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145787/bluetooth-printer-issue-in-android