# Android bluetooth printer

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth

I have to develop an app for Android tablets that demands printing files to a Bluetooth printer.

Printing over Bluetooth is one of the most important features of my app.

I tried this [project](https://github.com/pradeepksingh/Android-Bluetooth-Printer) and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14154840/3626214).

It doesn't work, nor reporting any error - do not print.

Any suggestion with bluetooth printer?

Comment: Does it gets paired, succesfully?

Comment: yes, appear `Bluetooth` icon printer and tablet

Comment: You should just add a share button. And tell the users to "share" it via Bluetooth and select the printer.

Comment: I know the theory but can not apply the practice

Comment: @Aspicas : Hi, do you get solution for this?

Comment: @Jayshree I had to make my own plugin to make it works...

Comment: @Aspicas: Can you share that plugin?.

Comment: @Jayshree I'm so sorry... it was for antoher company i can't share for privacy contract reasons...but if you post your code, everyone can help you to solve it. =)

Comment: @Aspicas :  Ok ..

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to save data to a file, like pdf or html or like it
Then share it through Intent
But the point is that on device API less that 19, Shared printer must be installed, then it is possible to print, have you installed any share printer app? 
It is like File browser, which user need to install

Answer (score 0):

I used Woosim's [PORTI-W40](http://www.woosim.com/english/bbs/message/message.view.do?boardId=4&messageId=906&messageCategoryId=59&listReturnURL=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.woosim.com%2Fenglish%2Fbbs%2Fmessage%2Fmessage.list.do%3FboardId%3D4%26messageCategoryId%3D59) printer to integrate bluetooth printing in my application. To integrate this, you have to download the SDK and [user manual](http://www.woosim.com/english/bbs/message/download.list.do?messageCategoryId=13&boardId=4&messageId=67) from Woosim and can integrate it. By the you can check the printer configuration using the [Woosim BT Printer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.woosim.android.print&hl=en) testing app from google play. If this app is successfully printing the test page, then your configuration is fine.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi can you share the SDK please? Thanks!